# extract the dictionary inside list of dictionary based on specific condition - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary as shown below

```
d4 = {
    "blue": 
        [
          {
              "type": "linear",
              "start_date": "2020-10-01T20:00:00.000Z",
              "end_date": "2020-10-20T20:00:00.000Z",
              "n_days":3,
              "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
              "case":"worst"
          }],
    'cate' : 'C',
    'prob': 0.2
    
     }
```

OR

```
d5 = {
    "white": 
        [
          {
              "type": "constant",
              "start_date": "2020-10-08T20:00:00.000Z",
              "end_date": "2020-10-25T20:00:00.000Z",
              "n_days":18,
              "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
              "case":"best"
          }],
    'cate' : 'A',
    'prob': 0.3
    
     }
```

From the above I would like write a function which should return dictionary inside the 'blue' or 'white' key.

Function could be like this

```
def dict_inside_blue_or_white(d):
```

Expected output:

1. If `d4` is the input to above function

   dict_inside_blue_or_white(d4)

Should give

```
{
              "type": "linear",
              "start_date": "2020-10-01T20:00:00.000Z",
              "end_date": "2020-10-20T20:00:00.000Z",
              "n_days":3,
              "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
              "case":"worst"
          }
```

2. If `d5` is the input to the function

   dict_inside_blue_or_white(d5)

Should give output as shown below.

```
{
              "type": "constant",
              "start_date": "2020-10-08T20:00:00.000Z",
              "end_date": "2020-10-25T20:00:00.000Z",
              "n_days":18,
              "coef":[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1],
              "case":"best"
          }
```

I tried below code

```
def dict_inside_blue_or_white(d):
    for i in ['blue'] or ['white']:
        return d[i][0]
```

it worked for d4. but if I pass d5 then it is giving below error.

```
KeyError: 'blue'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
for i in ['blue'] or ['white']
```

That's the issue.
It will be evaluate as `['blue']`.
Because `['blue']` is truly,
You could use `print(['blue'] or ['white'])` to see the result.

For your case, you could use:

```
def dict_inside_blue_or_white(d):
     for i in ['blue', 'white']:
        if i in d:
            return d[i][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

for the specif case of "blue" and "white" here is the function:

```
def dict_inside_blue_or_white(d):
    for element in d:
        if element in ["blue", "white"]:
            dic=d[element][0]
            return dic
```

and the output, for example for d4:

```
print(dict_inside_blue_or_white(d4))
{'type': 'linear','start_date': '2020-10-01T20:00:00.000Z','end_date': '2020-10-20T20:00:00.000Z', 'n_days': 3, 'coef': [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], 'case': 'worst'}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you love the one-liner then try this very simple and easy snippet.

```
def dict_inside_blue_or_white(d):
    x = [d.get(item) for item in ['blue', 'white'] if item in d]
    return x[0][0]

print(dict_inside_blue_or_white(d5))
```